# How should I fit cementboard underlayment around a supply pipe collar?

Tags: plumbing, tile

I am getting ready to put down Cement Board Underlayment (CBU) on the floor for a tile job, and the toilet water supply pipe that comes through the floor has a plastic collar around it.

It will interfere with the CBU.  How do the pros handle a situation like this?

[image]

Comment: Sorry.  It is an abbreviation for Cement Backer Board.  Not sure where the "U" comes in.  I actually googled what it meant, and came up dry.  Thanks for your response below.

Comment: I meant by editing your post. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several acceptable options:

1. Remove the collar and rely on mortar to retain the pipe.
2. Remove the collar and apply silicone to the hole to retain the pipe.
3. Chisel out a space in the subfloor for the collar and lower it so that it's flush.
4. Cut your cementboard around it and mortar over it (or just tile over the void).

Comment: I think I'll go the silicone route.  Was thinking of that spray foam, but don't want to buy a can for such a small job.  I am a little leery of having thinset around copper.  I have heard various conflicting things that it could cause corrosion - or it doesn't cause corrosion.  But I don't want to chance it :)